# Why does my equals method not recognize object variables?

Tags: java, equals

I am simply trying to write an equals method that compares students names and sections.  If the names and sections are the same, then the equals method should print true.  Otherwise it should print false.

Below is what I have so far.

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int section;

    public Student(String name, int section) {
        this.name = name;
        this.section = section;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object y) {

        if (this.name.equals(y.name) && this.section.equals(y.section)) {
            return true;    
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is with `y.name` and `y.section`.  Eclipse tells me `name` and `section` cannot be resolved to a field.

My question is, can anybody show me how to fix my code so that I can compare student names and sections using the .equals() method?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to "box" and "unbox" whatever y is.  In your case y is probably really a Student.

Comment: It doesn't related with the question (question already has been resolved by @Thilo), but `if(condition){return true;}else{return false;}` can be replaced with `return condition;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override  // you should add that annotation
public boolean equals(Object y) {
```

Your `y` is any `Object`, not necessarily a `Student`.

You need to have code like

```
if (y == this) return true;
if (y == null) return false;
if (y instanceof Student){
  Student s = (Student) y;
  // now you can access s.name and friends
```

Comment: trying to put an answer below a new question FIRST  is a real struggle. I give up.

Comment: @Blauhirn You don't need to be first. Jon Skeet often is last to answer :)

Comment: @Blauhim Good. The important thing is to be right, not first. Truth is not a function of time.

Comment: @Pshemo I know. was just referring to questions like this where the solution is rather obvious. no offense.

Comment: There's no need to use `instanceof` **and** check for `null`, since `instanceof` yields `false` for `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. I'm not sure, but I think Eclipse should this function too - 'add standard equals method' - use it and then your IDE generate absolutely right equals method... But it is about coding speed optimization. Now let's tell about equals method. Normally `equals` method contract defines `transitiveness` on itself... So if a equal to b then b equal to a. In this case it is recommended to have strict restrictions:

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
  if (x == this) {
    return true; // here we just fast go-out on same object
  }
  if (x == null || ~x.getClass().equals(this.getClass())) {
    return false; // in some cases here check `instanceof`
                  // but as I marked above - we should have
                  // much strict restriction
                  // in other ways we can fail on transitiveness
                  // with sub classes
  }
  Student student = (Student)y;
  return Objects.equals(name, student.name)
         && Objects.equals(section, student.section);
  //please note Objects - is new (java 8 API)
  //in order of old API usage you should check fields equality manaully.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to type cast Object to Student class;

```
Student std = (Student)y;
```

Comment: you should not do that unconditionally, though